# Terminology for a function computed by a finite-state transducer?

Tags: functions, terminology, computer-science

A [finite-state transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) is a generalization of a finite state machine that accepts an input string and produces an output string (instead of just accepting or rejecting).  Is there a name for a function $f : \Sigma_1^* \rightarrow \Sigma_2^*$ that can be computed by a finite-state transducer?  Functions of this form computable by Turing machines are typically called computable functions, and I was curious if there was an analogous term for FSTs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a Finite state transduc$tion$.

Answer (score 0):

Finite-state transducers are generally nondeterministic. Therefore, in general, they compute binary relations (of strings). The relations that can be computed by finite-state transducers are exactly *regular relations*. They are also called *rational relations* (and *finite-state transductions*, as pointed out in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157594/835051)).